# Change image using multiple select and javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html-select

I need to change the image on my website using 2 `select` for colour and size.

e.g. If I choose the `option` "Red" under the colour `select`, and then I choose the `option` "Small" under the size `select`, the image should be "small_red.png".
Similarly, if I choose red and large, then the image should be "red_large.png"

Thus far, I only know how to do it for 1 `select`, but not multiple `select`.

Here's my html:

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.png">

<select id="colour" onChange="swapImage()">
<option value="img/red.png">Red</option>
<option value="img/green.png">Green</option>
</select>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var change = document.getElementById("colour");
    image.src = change.value;   
};
</script>
```

Comment: @AspiringAqib *Thus far, I only know how to do it for 1 select, but not multiple select.* there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  img = document.getElementById('imageToSwap'),
  colour = document.getElementById('colour'),
  size = document.getElementById('size'),
  change;

change = function (evt) {
  img.src = ['img/', size.value, '_', colour.value, '.png'].join('');
};

colour.addEventListener('change', change, false);
size.addEventListener('change', change, false);
```

with:

```
<img id="imageToSwap">

<select id="colour">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
  <option value="small">Small</option>
  <option value="big">Big</option>
</select>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/iwezad/2/

---

though, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) this could be shortend a lot, and you'd get rid of some browser quirks regarding `addEventListener`.

---

**jQuery version**:

```
$('#colour, #size').on('change', function() {
  $('#imageToSwap').prop('src', 
    ['img/', $('#size').val(), '_', $('#colour').val(), '.jpg'].join('')    
  );
});
```

Comment: @ATOzTOA [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

You can always concatenate values from selects.

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.png">

<select id="colour" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="red.png">Red</option>
    <option value="green.png">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
```

And in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapImage(){
        var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
        var color = document.getElementById("colour").value;
        var size = document.getElementById("size").value;

        image.src = "img/" + size + "_" + color;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="imageToSwap" >
<select id="colour"  onchange="swapImage()">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onchange="swapImage()">
<option value="small">Small</option>`
<option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function swapImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
        var color = document.getElementById("colour").value;
        var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
        var imagename = size + '_' + color + '.png';

        image.src = "img/" + imagename;
    }
</script>
```