# Change image src by using multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, select, multi-select

I would like to change image using multiple select.

Referring to the [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069917/change-image-using-multiple-select-and-javascript) 
The structure will be exactly the same as the above code.

But using `<select>` and  `<option>` is not suitable for my case.
I would like to use `<ul>` and `<li>` (or `<div>` and `<a>` )instead.
I have tried to edit with it, but the javascript cannot recognize the value.

I am totally new to javascript.
And I don't know how to modify the code.
Please help and many thanks.

Here's the html:

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.jpg">

<select id="colour" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapImage(){
        var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
        var color = document.getElementById("colour").value;
        var size = document.getElementById("size").value;

        image.src = "img/" + size + "_" + color + ".jpg";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Add the html as you want it and I help fix the javascript

Comment: You got answers so I will not add mine as it will be similar

Comment: I have tried those, but it seems can't support multi-condition to change the src, there will have at least two conditions need to set in order to change the img src directly from the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in different ways. I will propose mine using data attributes to store `src` values. Consider this code.

HTML:

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4">

<ul class="select">
    <li class="option active" data-value="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4">Red</li>
    <li class="option" data-value="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1">Green</li>
    <li class="option" data-value="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2">Yellow</li>
</ul>
```

and JS:

```
var $image = $('#imageToSwap');

$('.select').on('click', '.option', function() {
    $image.prop('src', $(this).data('value'));
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8f669/

### UPD Support multiple selects

```
var $image = $('#imageToSwap');

var $selects = $('.select').on('click', '.option', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    var src = 'http://lorempixel.com/{size}/{size}/{group}/{image}';
    $selects.each(function() {
        src = src.replace(RegExp('\\{' + $(this).data('name') + '\\}', 'g'), $(this).find('.active').data('value'));
    });
    $image.prop('src', src);
});
```

Note how src is constructed. `'http://lorempixel.com/{size}/{size}/{group}/{image}'`. It has tokens corresponding to select lists. It brings maximal flexibility. You jsut add new select list with proper `data-name="xxx"` attribute, and here we go, you can use token `{xxx}` in src url.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8f669/2/

Comment: I have tried this, but it can't support multi-condition also

Comment: What is multi-conditions?

Comment: like choosing 
red+small=>red-small.jpg
red+big=>red-big.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This support multiple condition. You should set a default value in the ul's `data-selected` (or in the swapImage function if any `data-selected` is empty).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t49jQ/1/

CSS

```
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="">

<ul id="color" data-selected=''>
    <li data-color='red' onClick="swapImage(this,1)">Red</li>
    <li data-color='green' onClick="swapImage(this,1)">Green</li>
</ul>

<ul id="size" data-selected=''>
    <li data-size='small' onClick="swapImage(this,2)">Small</li>
    <li data-size='big' onClick="swapImage(this,2)">Big</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function swapImage(el,type){

        var el_color = document.getElementById("color");
        var el_size = document.getElementById("size");
        var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");

        if (type == 1) {    
            el_color.setAttribute('data-selected',el.getAttribute('data-color'));

        } else if (type == 2) {
            el_size.setAttribute('data-selected', el.getAttribute('data-size'));
        }

        image.src = "img/" + el_size.getAttribute('data-selected') + "_" + el_color.getAttribute('data-selected') + ".jpg";

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code using ul li and jquery

```
<img src="" id="image_tag"/>

 <ul id="test">
  <li data-image="img/test.jpg">Image 1</li>
  <li data-image="img/test1.jpg">Image 2</li>
</ul>


 <script>
   $(function(){
     $('#test li').click(function(){
         $('#image_tag').attr('src',$(this).data('image'));
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems can't support multi-condition to change the src

Comment: can you post ur html and script here.